# How to download a file with nodejs to local computer?

Tags: node.js, angular, http, server

I'm building a server, and i want to allow downloading files.
FrontEnd with angular - and i have DB Service there.

BackEnd with NodeJS+express.

I have at BE router & controller and I wrote some code that works - but not for all cases.

If i type in browser the URL for downloading, say "http://localhost:3000/api/files/download/somefile"
All works as excpected and the file is downloaded to my PC.

but if i set a function on my FE to call that download function (lets say, after some button was clicked) - it doesn't work, and i get an error: "Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:3000/api/files/download/some%20file"

My server headers, as i wrote in app.js:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));


app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.setHeader(
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
        "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
        );
        res.setHeader(
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
            "GET, PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS"
            );
            next();
        });
```

my function at the controller:

```
exports.downloadFile = (req, res, next) => {
var data = req.params.file;

fs.writeFile("temp.txt", data, (err) => {
    if (err){
 console.log("error: "+err);
}
    console.log("Successfully Written to File!");
    var filePath = "temp.txt"; 
    var fileName = "downloaded_file.txt"; 

    res.download(filePath, fileName, (err) => {
        console.log("download error: "+err)
    });
});
```

my call at DB Service:

```
downloadExp(file: string) {      
   this.http.get("http://localhost:3000/api/files/download" + file) 
}
```

What I'm doing wrong? how i can enable download from frontend, after a button was clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use FileSaver in my frontend to download files.
I know link-only answers aren't so good but my own code is essentially the same as the examples in the readme here. https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/

Comment: This is very good, Thanks!
I didn't know you can download files like this, i tought you must save them on server and only then to download.